# Show more than one post on the main page excluding certain category

Tags: wp-query

I'm currently running WordPress 4.5 with a WooTheme called **The Morning After**. I decided to change a few things here and there, but encountered some issues regarding the `posts_per_page` argument used in the `WP_Query` object. The intention is to show more than one post (3 or 4 posts) and ignore the category **Featured articles**.

```
$args = array(
    'posts_per_page'   => 2,
    'category__not_in' => get_cat_ID('Featured articles')
);

$query = new WP_Query($args);

while ( $query->have_posts() ) { 
    $query->the_post();
    echo '<li>' . get_the_title() . '</li>';
};
```

What am I doing wrong? Result is 4 posts including the posts that are in the category `Featured articles`.

Comment: it should be `WP_Query` , i assume that's mistake you have done while asking

Comment: Do you want to alter  main loop or adding secondary loop ?

Comment: Specify post type inside you query

Comment: Yes it was a mistake while asking. The WP_Query is, by default, using post_type=post. This is the main loop I altered.

Answer (score 0):

If you are altering **main query** then use [`pre_get_posts`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/pre_get_posts) filter instead of [`WP_Query`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query).

```
add_action('pre_get_posts','wpse224610_alter_query');
function wpse224610_alter_query($query){
      $cat_id = get_cat_ID('Featured articles');
      $exclude_cat_id = -$cat_id;
      if( !is_admin() && $query->is_main_query() ){
         $query->set( 'cat', $exclude_cat_id );
         $query->set( 'posts_per_page', 4 );
      }
}
```

And the main loop will be

```
if( have_posts() ):
    while( have_posts() ): the_post();
       //The loop
    endwhile;
endif;
```

Check the return value of `$cat_id` , is it 0 or **Featured articles** category id ? check whether you spelled category name correctly as it is in the admin ?

From your code i assume you are trying to do secondary loop but as you told it's main loop , use above mentioned filter.

[Read more](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/50761/when-to-use-wp-query-query-posts-and-pre-get-posts)

Comment: Perhaps I'm the one being confused what the main loop exactly is. I thought it was the main loop because it is the first loop in that file, which is home.php. Perhaps the WP_Query in wp-includes/functions.php is considered the main loop? I'll read the url you attached and see how it goes.

Comment: check this also http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/1753/43098

Comment: It is running local.

Comment: Thank you so much, it was indeed not the main loop that I should have altered. But instead just use get_posts($args). Now it works.